# ninject.mvc3 not loading modules

Tags: ninject

I'm using ninject mvc3 via nuget in a MVC4 webapi application. No changes made to global.asax I have created a ninjectmode and placed it in the bin folder. I'm noticing that the line
' bootstrapper.Initialize( CreateKernel)'  in NinjectWebCommon.cs is throwing an exception 'Sequence contains no elements'.
If I delete the  the dll containing my ninject module the error disappears.
What am I doing wrong? I would like go be able to use NinjectModules to separate concerns in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Apparently, when you add Ninject.MVC3 to a class library project via Nuget, it adds an "App_Start" folder similar to how it does for a web application project. This was causing the above error. I removed the App_Start folder and life is good once again.